# C# Change form from async static class

Tags: c#, server, client

I have two small applications made with C# .net in visual studios (2017).

One is a **server**, and the other is a **client**. Using `System.Net` & `System.Net.Sockets` I've made the server accept connection requests in an asynchronous manner *(Multiple clients can disconnect and reconnect at any given time.)*

The server application is a C# .NET Windows Form, with a couple GUI elements *(such as a richtextbox or label.)* 
The client application is a C# .NET Console, nothing much on it actually.

I'm facing a problem though. Inside the server application I've created a class file *`(Server.cs)`* that has a non-static class which creates the server and listens using sockets. The methods it uses to listen and receive data are static, and since it handles clients in an asynchronous manner it uses another thread.

I'm calling the server to start by running this inside my form file `Server.SetupServer();`

---

**Problem:** Inside `Server.cs` there is a method that receives data from the client and writes a message box displaying the data, this works fine. The problem occurs when I want to change this and make it display the data inside of a label instead *`(label1)`*, this doesn't work. I can't even seem to select the `label1` element from inside of the `Server.cs` file at all. [*(Typing it out doesn't seem to show anything in IntelliSense)*](https://ibb.co/yWHzt60)

Using delegates is an answer I've heard often and this worked for me when I made a dummy server application that instead of a seperate file for the server class, it was just a class made in the form file itself. I could select the `label1` element by using a `this.label1.BeginInvoke( //code here )`.

---

I figure this happens becuase either:

1. I'm wrong on how the Async Socket methods works, and a new thread isn't created
2. The Form file and `Server.cs` file are created differently than each other (Form being an instance while the server file is different)
3. Or I'm terribly wrong on both

If someone could point me in a direction of what I should learn before this, that would be great. I have a couple reference books I'll be reading to gain more knowledge on the concept of threads and delegates if that helps.

---

*Thank you for reading my mess.*

Comment: can you post the code you have tried so far

Comment: What do you mean “can’t select the label?” Are you saying you don’t know how? Get an error? Does something you don’t expect?

Comment: @Rahul Yes I'll upload a pastebin of some sort in a second, I'll try to cut unnecessary code to make it easy to read.

Comment: No, no link of code ... rather copy/paste in question

Comment: @JohnWu Sorry let me re-explain, inside the server file I can't seem to type out the element. IntelliSense doesn't even show it. As in `Form1.label1` doesn't show at all.

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information. It would help if you included the declaration for `Form1` and the `label1` property, as well as the code you are writing that does not compile.

Comment: @WatchYoJet as per your `code-image` try creating an `instance` of **`Form1`** then call the property `label1` from that instance. As what you are trying to do is access the `Form1` content from a separate class which is not supported without creating an instance first.

Comment: you may try passing the Form1's current object as context to your server.cs constructor.

Comment: @vikscool Alright I'll try to create an instance of it first. Is it right to do it such as in the `Program.cs` file? Going to the top above `Main` and declaring it: `static Form1 form;` then doing `Application.Run(form);` in `Main`

Comment: @WatchYoJet Yes, you can do that but be careful as this will create a separate instance of the `Form1` if there is already one visible. Or as per @Timon suggested passing the instance of the `Form1` in the `Server.cs` method and set the `Label1.Text` property or simply create another method in the `Form1` which will have access to the `label1` and pass your values to that method by calling it from your Server method.

Comment: @vikscool Alright I didn't get much success trying to create an instance and accessing it inside the `Server.cs` file. I'll try the other way

Comment: @Timon and vikscool Thank you a lot, this has done the trick. I used delegates to handle changing the label text. It seems kind of like a ragtag way of doing it though. But I'm very new to coding this kind of stuff, so I can use this and clean it up more to produce better results. Thank you!